# Array doesn't print correct values beyond a certain limit of indices

Tags: c++

The following code gives a very wrong and random output for inputs greater than 5,5 (respective values of m and n wrt the code below). Why is it so? What might be the fix to this?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int m,n;

        cin>>m>>n;

        int i,j,k;
       int a[m][n];
       k = 1;
      a[0][0] == 1;

       for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            cout<<(a[0][0]+k*(j+1))<<" ";
        }
        
        k = k+2;
        cout<<'\n';
       }
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is wrong and non-standard. It does not exist on Linux with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: If the input for `m` and `n` is negative, you have undefined behavior. And your program uses only one cell (the `a[0][0]` one) of `a`. Did you try to debug your program with [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) ?

Comment: Accessing beyond the boundaries of an array is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, `a[0][0] == 1` has no side effect (you test for equality, and discard the result of the test). Perhaps you want an assignment `a[0][0] = 1;`

Comment: Every element of the array `a` is uninitialized.

Comment: There are a lot of potential issues with your code. So If you're trying to learn C++, I recommend you first go over some good recent training material (a book) or a site like https://www.learncpp.com/. Your current code seems to be inspired from sites that are either competitive or try to teach you about data-structures (instead of C++) and while the teach you about problem solving they don't really do a good job of teaching C++.  To write code with less bugs it is important you know about the standard library as well (https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: @PepijnKramer In the given code, there is no out of bound access of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile this withg warnings enabled you get:

```
<source>:18:15: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
      a[0][0] == 1;
      ~~~~~~~~^~~~
<source>:18:15: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
      a[0][0] == 1;
              ^~
              =
1 warning generated.
```

You don't want comparison there but `a[0][0] = 1;`.

---

Now for other stuff you shouldn't do:

- `int a[m][n];` is not C++ but a compiler extension. Use `std::vector`.
- `int a[m][n];` leaves the array uninitialized and you only ever write to `a[0][0]` (if you fix the ==).
- `a` is never ever used except for `a[0][0]`. The whole array is utterly pointless. A single `const int a = 1;` would do the same.
- `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is wrong and doesn't even exist on many compilers
- `using namespace std;` is overly broad. You never want/need all of std. Be more selective.